# Can you make a linux system halt and boot my Raspberry-pi at certain times?

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, shutdown, raspbian, scheduling

How to make a system turn itself off and back on at different times. For example I would have my "server" turn off at 4 A.M  then turn back on at 5 A.M every day. Is this possible? I am using a Raspberry-pi with the most recent version of Raspbian.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to do that?  Maybe there will be another way to achieve your ultimate goal.  This may be an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a mains timer between the mains outlet and the power supply.

Shut down the Raspberry at 4 A.M using a cron job, then set the timer to cut the mains a bit later and to restore power at 5 A.M.

Comment: Methinks this would work well, such timers are cheap and easy to use.

Comment: Don't forget to keep an eye on it during Daylight Savings' time changes! You will end up either cutting power before running `halt`, or having it only on for one hour and then off for the rest of the day.

Comment: @IQAndreas: You'll only end up cutting power early if the timer is set for DST times while the Pi isn't using DST. If the Pi uses DST, but the timer doesn't, all that will happen is that the Pi will stay in the "halted" state for an hour (it will start shutting down at 4AM; the timer will cut the power just after 5AM and bring it up again at 6AM).

Answer (score 12):

You can suspend or hibernate your system and then automatically wake it up with `rtcwake` command. For example to suspend (to ram) and resume in 60 seconds do

```
rtcwake -s 60 -m mem
```

To hibernate (suspend to disk) in one hour from now and resume in two hours:

```
sleep 3600; rtcwake -s 3600 -m disk
```

You can also wakeup the system at given time with `-t` option which takes seconds since 1970 as an argument. Run `man rtcwake` for more info.

Comment: Good answer (+1) but this will not work on the raspberry pi because it does not have an RTC chip (it needs an `ntp` service to get the correct time at boot).

Comment: Indeed I don't have experience with raspberry pi. If this answer won't be massively downvoted I will leave it as a possible solution for other platforms.

Comment: I think this is a good answer in-case anyone was looking for a non raspberry-pi system.

Answer (score 8):

You can get it to turn off whenever you like with `halt` or `shutdown now` or whatever you prefer; schedule that with `cron` or a custom sleeping background process.

In addition to the real time wakeup implemented by normal PC hardware (which the pi isn't) and usable via `rtcwake`, there is [wake-on-LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN).

**Unfortunately, neither of those will work on the raspberry pi**, since you can't:

- Suspend to RAM.
- Kill or reset the power, except by pulling the plug.
- Suspend to storage, except (possibly) by doing some modifications to the OS configuration (as is, raspbian uses a compressed ramdisk for swap) -- and even then the bootloader will not give you the option to bypass, either.

The pi hardware does not have any "power management" features at all beyond reboot.  If it is plugged in, it is on, and it remains on after the system halts.

Answer (score 3):

Shutting down is easy, use the `poweroff` command - put it in a crontab if you want. Starting up, however, is harder as the OS doesn't run when the machine is stopped, so you can't just add a cron job and expect it to run. On some PCs the `rtcwake` command will indeed work but on some it won't, and you may need to tinker with the BIOS settings.

For the Raspberry, as [@goldilocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167403/80886) answered, you can't use that - the only solution will be a hardware one with a microcontroller, an RTC and a relay or MOSFET through which the Raspberry's power line will go. The microcontroller should be connected to the Pi's GPIO ports and you should make yourself an `rtcwake` equivalent that talks to that microcontroller and gives it the current time and the wakeup/shutdown time.

Answer (score 3):

If you can live with adding a a separate board, the WittyPi give you the means to start and stop the Raspberry Pi at scheduled times. I found it to use 1.7 to 2.4 mA @ 5VDC while in sleep mode with power connected. The internal battery holds the RTC if the power is disconnected.
http://www.uugear.com/witty-pi-realtime-clock-power-management-for-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 1):

To schedule a server shutdown, you could schedule `/sbin/shutdown -h now` in your `cron` table.  For startup, some system BIOSs allow you to automatically start the system up at a certain time of day.  If your BIOS does not support that, you could look into having another host on the same network send a Wake-On-Lan packet, but that also requires BIOS support and another running host on the network.